# Fire jQuery event before postback occurs - asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've been looking for a method of adding a jQuery event to a button which once clicked will fire the event followed by the asp postback.

Adding the event is easy enough the issue however is delaying the asp postback temporarily.

Asp Code (Events added in C#):

```
<input runat="server" ClientIDMode="static "id="cancelButton">
```

JQuery Code:

```
var cancelBtn = jQuery('#cancelButton');

cancelBtn.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var cancelBtnEvent = cancelBtn[0].click;

    jQuery(pnl).animate({
        height: 200
    }, 300, 'swing', function () {
        cancelBtnEvent();
    });
});
```

In the code above I am adding a click event to the button, 'cancelBtn' is an input[type="button"]. The event will stop the defaults, save the click function to call later, do some animation then call the click function. However this fails with the error invalid object call.

So my question:

How should this be done? or Can my solution be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Is 'cancelBtn' an anchor tag `<a>`?

Comment: Apologises should have that clear, will update question.

Comment: Please explain reasoning behind downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Here is a simple trick that would work for you. Sorry, I didn't noticed the question before, carefully.

```
var IsFirstLoad = true;// Declare globally (outside ready function)
        cancelBtn.click(function (e) {
            if (IsFirstLoad) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            jQuery(pnl).animate({
                height: 200
            }, 300, 'swing', function () {
                jQuery('#cancelButton').click();
                IsFirstLoad=false;
            });
        });
```

Answer posted first.(won't work in this scenerio). Sorry!

```
jQuery(pnl).animate({
        height: 200
    }, 300, 'swing', function () {
        jQuery(cancelBtn).click();
    });
```

Try using `jQuery(cancelBtn).click();` instead of `cancelBtnEvent();`. If `cancelBtn` is a jQuery element simply `cancelBtn.click()` would be enough.

Comment: This won't work either, please check out comments on other posts to understand the problem a little more

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer because it does work. However preferably I would like a method without a global variable as there will be multiple occurrences of "pnl", but I did not mention that. SO this is correct.. Thanks for your suggestion, much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the global variable for a data attribute on the button itself and works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you sure that your selector `cancelBtn` is correct? ASP.net modifies asp elements ids, so that you cannot address them by `$("MyElementId")` any more. Instead you will have to use e.g. `$("[ID$=MyElementId]")`. So what kind of object is `cancelBtn`?

Why do you save the click event in a variable? Instead you could call it directly:

```
jQuery(pnl).animate({
    height: 200
}, 300, 'swing', function () {
    jQuery(cancelBtn).click();
});
```

Note that you do not need to get the DOM element by using `cancelBtn[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I'm 100% sure its the correct element. Have debugged in IE and Visual Studio which shows it correct. The 'cancelBtn' is an input[type='button']. In order to get the jQuery to fire before the asp does a post back I need to delay the original asp click event, I was hoping by saving it I could call the function directly in the completion delegate. If I simply call jQuery click the 'e.preventDefault' will prevent the asp event from firing. (If this makes sense)

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe the default behaviour of the button is still prevented when you call the click event. 2 suggestions: Either try to use a timeout `setTimeout(function(){jQuery(cancelBtn).click();},300);` after the call of animate. Or you could try to use 2 buttons: one hidden (do not set `visible=false` but wrap it in a div and set it's style to `display:none;`!) asp button for the postback and one usual `input[type='button']` button for the user click. Then you click on the hidden button via almost the same JS for the user button.

Comment: The double button isn't a bad solution, its however my plan B at the minute. I'm going to try using _doPostBack(). Then in the page load of the c# code I will check the '_EVENTTARGET' and call a method.

Answer (score 0):

this is also possible:

```
jQuery(cancelBtn).trigger("click");
```